# Cannot map custom js to my custom template in bigcommerce shopica theme with stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

I 've added custom page and js for it in stencil bigcommerce.

It works fine locally but  when I push it on bigcommerce, it does not work well.

I have added custom template `template/pages/custom/page/custom-layout.html` and I've added custom js for it in `assets/js/custom/custom.js`.

I've configured some loading settings in `assets/js/app.js` as follows:

```
const customClasses = {
    'pages\\custom\\page\\custom-layout': () => import('./custom/custom')
}
```

It works locally; but, on a server, it does not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your customClasses object should use forward slashes like so:

```
"pages/custom/page/custom-layout": () => import("./custom/custom")
```

You should also make sure that your `custom.js` file is extending the `PageManager` class like so:

```
import PageManager from "../page-manager";

export default class CustomClass extends PageManager {
    constructor(context) {
        super(context);
        // other constructor code here
    }

    onReady() {
        // your code for the onReady event here
    }

    // ... any other code
}
```

If this is done properly your custom JS class will be injected to the page. However, once you bundle and upload your theme, you must also make sure to apply your custom template to the page, as the config.stencil.json file is not packaged with your theme. This can be done from within the BigCommerce control panel by going to **Storefront > Web Pages > [Your page]** and changing the **Template Layout File** accordingly.

Comment: The choice for forward or back slash depends if you are using Mac/Linux or Windows :

const customClasses = {
    'pages/custom/product/customProd': () => import('./theme/custom'), // Mac/Linux
    'pages\\custom\\product\\customProd': () => import('./theme/custom'), // Windows
};